# Count parent child child nodes

Tags: javascript, html

So I want to know how do I get count of parent child child childs for example:

```js
const parent = document.querySelectorAll('.parent');
parent.forEach(el => {
  const ul = el.querySelector('.child3-child');
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.textContent = ul.childNodes.length;
  el.append(div);
});
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">
   text
  </div>
  <div class="child2">
   text
  </div>
  <div class="child3">
    <ul class="child3-child">
     <li>
      some text...
     </li>
    <ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

And now I want count how many `<ul class="child3-child">` has child elements in this case it has only 1 `li`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use [`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children) instead of `childNodes`. The former includes HTML Elements while the latter includes text nodes.
- Close your `</ul>` tag properly or else the borwser will think it's opening a nested element.

```js
const parent = document.querySelectorAll('.parent');
parent.forEach(el => {
  const ul = el.querySelector('.child3-child');
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.textContent = ul.children.length;
  el.append(div);
});
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">
   text
  </div>
  <div class="child2">
   text
  </div>
  <div class="child3">
    <ul class="child3-child">
     <li>
      some text...
     </li>
    </ul> <!--- This wasn't properly closed -->
  </div>
</div>
```